# Why does gradle run every task in gradle.build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm very new to gradle and have a basic question.

When I add a custom task to my gradle.build file and call "gradlw build" or "gradle clean" or any other gradle command, 
it automatically runs my custom task.

Is that how things work in gradle? run every task in the build file?
Is there  way to run a task only when I want it manually?

Answer (score 5):

```
task foo {
  println 'hello'
}
```

That creates a task, and during the **configuration** of the task, it tells gradle to execute `println 'hello'`. Every task is configured at each build, because gradle needs to know what its configuration is to know if the task must be executed or not.

```
task foo << {
  println 'hello'
}
```

That creates a task, and during the **execution** of the task, it tells gradle to execute `println 'hello'`. So the code will only be executed if you explicitly chose to run the task `foo`, or a task that depends on `foo`.

It's equivalent to

```
task foo {
  doLast {
    println 'hello'
  }
}
```

You chose not to post your code, probably assuming that gradle was acting bizarrely, and that your code had nothing to do with the problem. So this is just a guess, but you probably used the first incorrect code rather than the second, correct one.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't aware of the difference between those two task definitions. Thanks for your explanation.