# Run gradle task only when called specifically

Tags: gradle

I have a `build.gradle` file that creates a java `WAR` file. This file is used in one stage of a Docker multi stage build to generate a Docker Image that I use in production, staging, etc... (the configuration files / secrets are outside the image).

But in development, although most of the time I use the normal build to generate a WAR file (or an exploded WAR), and it works fine, **sometimes I want to just execute a single java file** with a main class in my project.

I achieved that adding the following to the file:

```gradle
task execFile(type: JavaExec) {
    main = mainClass

    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    if (System.getProperty('debug', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs "-Xdebug", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8788,server=y,suspend=y"
    }

    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}
```

Then I'm able to execute the file passing system properties with:

```
gradle execFile -PmainClass=com.mysite.MyClass -Dsomeprop=somevalue
```

And if I want to debug i run:

```
gradle execFile -PmainClass=com.mysite.MyClass -Dsomeprop=somevalue -Ddebug=true
```

This way I can execute (and debug) single files, which is great in some cases during development, but the problem is that this code is executed even if I dont run `execFile` explicitly.

This causes errors when building and generating the WAR file, so what I'm doing is commenting these lines, uncommenting when I run single files, and commenting again (**when I remember**) after I run the files, before pushing the git repo (otherwise the docker build process ends up with errors).

**This is very bad, I know.**

Based on what I understand, that code is run during the **configuration phase**, and to make the code run in the **execution** of the task, I could include the code inside a `doLast` method (or use the shorthand `<<`):

[Why does gradle run every task in gradle.build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674792/why-does-gradle-run-every-task-in-gradle-build)

But in this case I get the error `No main class specified`, probably due to the same reasons stated in this discussion:

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/javexec-error-no-main-class-specified/12731

> The JavaExec task has a task action which executes the Java program.
>   By using <<, you’re adding the configuration of the main, classpath,
>   and args as a task action as well. When the task action provided by
>   the JavaExec runs, the second task action to configure these values
>   has not run yet. You likely want to configure these values in the
>   configuration phase, not in a task action by removing the <<.

The error doesn't happen if I remove the `doLast` method, but the initial problem would remain unsolved.

**So what I want to know is if there is a way (and how) to make what's inside the `execFile` task run only when this task is called explicitly.**

(so that it won't cause any side effects when other tasks are run)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this problem with a wrapping task, by creating at runtime the desired JavaExec one inside its `doLast { }` closure.

For Groovy DSL:

```
task myTask {
    group = 'MyGroup'
    description = 'Runs Hello.java'
    dependsOn 'build'

    doLast {
        tasks.create('myTaskExec', JavaExec) {
            main = 'com.example.Hello'
            args = ['foo', 'bar']
            classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        }.exec()
    }
}
```

For Kotlin DSL:

```
tasks.register("myTask") {
    group = "MyGroup"
    description = "Runs Hello.java"
    dependsOn(mutableListOf("build"))

    doLast {
        tasks.create<JavaExec>("myTaskExec") {
            main = "com.example.Hello" 
            args = mutableListOf("foo", "bar")
            classpath = sourceSets.main.get().runtimeClasspath
        }.exec()
    }
}
```

Note that in both examples the dependencies to another task should be declared in the wrapping task and not in the JavaExec one.

With this change your task should be running only when called:

```
task execFile {
    dependsOn 'build'

    doLast {
        tasks.create('execFileJavaExec', JavaExec) {
            main = mainClass
            classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

            if (System.getProperty('debug', 'false') == 'true') {
                jvmArgs "-Xdebug", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8788,server=y,suspend=y"
            }

            systemProperties System.getProperties()
        }.exec()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this way the task `execFileJavaExec` will only be created if `execFile`, which is just a thin wrapper for the real task (`execFileJavaExec`), is run explicitly (because it's in the `doLast`). I was able to run in both ways with this (the normal `gradle build`, and also running a single file).

Comment: Thank you for this. Gradle: Why is such a simple ask so amazingly complicated?